# Discord.py making a kick command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am in a process of making a discord bot in python,so far I have made some small commands and now I am trying to add commands like kick and ban , and i have read the documentation from git hub and tried make the command and i got some error but I have fixed them but now the code for the kick command is neither giving a error nor sending a message in the discord channel this happening only when a non administrator trying to execute the command. I am using `has_premissions` to do this, becoz my bot will be in 3 to 4 servers

code is here:

```
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, why=None):
    await member.kick(reason=why)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"**{member} has been kicked from this server by {ctx.author}**")


@kick.error
async def kick_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.channel.send("Looks like you don't have the perm.")
```

*thanks in advance*

Comment: you have `@bot.command()` on the top? and add `raise(error)` at the end of your error handler, so you can see error

Comment: tried it but it is not working and ya i have added `@bot.command` on the top

Comment: My problem actually is that the command is working but it not sending a msg when a `non-adminstrator` uses the command , and there are no error in the code and also i have added all the `decorators.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you should use `@commands.has_permissions` instead of `has_permissions`.

Then add `@client.command()` top of the `async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, why=None):`

**EDIT**

If you have a problem with error handling, use

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
```

instead of `@kick.error`. So you can do this

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.channel.send("Looks like you don't have the perm.")
```

Comment: i had imported `@has_permissions` directly from discord.py and i have also added @client.commands before only but still it does not work

Comment: So you can kick members but if someone has no administrator permission, there's no error shows up, am I right?

Comment: ya , i wrote the code in such a way that if some who doesnt the prems then it should send `Looks like you don't have the perm.` but it not doing that.